# Is it possible to have personal backlogs and planning according to the prioritization of the tasks?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, resource-planning, prioritization

Microsoft Project is ok for setting up for Gannt Chart and baseline but it is not possible to see individual plans and schedules. Is it possible to integrate all?

is it possible to have personal backlog and plan according to the prioritization of the tasks? Probably, it is not possible. However, I had an idea, it might be possible with the whole ecosystem. (kind of an in one idea which is unlikely as you said)

Comment: Microsoft is an "ancient" technology. Teams is a new product / solution, an ecosystem in itself, promoting and based on Sharepoint. So my guess that integration is very unlikely. However, I might be wrong, I am curios if anyone attempted this.

Comment: @virolino thanks for the answer. I know it is ancient. Probably, I asked the question in the wrong way. the main question is actually, is it possible to personal backlogs and planning according to the prioritization of the tasks? Probably, it is not possible. However, I had an idea, it might be possible with the whole ecosystem. (kind of all in one idea which is unlikely as you said)

Comment: @alfonso, recommend you edit the question with the clarification; few people will read the comment.

Comment: @MCW I am new here and I am not sure what I should do. Do you mean how it is asked or should I confirm that it is answered?

Comment: Your comment said that you'd asked the wrong question - suggest you *edit the question* to clarify; I've started the edit for you.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot, this is why I would recommend looking at tools like https://teamhood.com/use-cases/project-management/ that incorporate all those feature sets as one coherent system.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Planner (in Teams) and Outlook are sort of integrated already.  The Microsoft oompa loompas are actively fiddling with how that integrates (Sharepoint being the connecting thread).  Watch what happens as they do ...

MS Project is out on its own little iceberg somewhere.  It's not really in the same ecosystem.  I doubt it will change very much now, if at all.

So practically, you may be looking at developing complicated projects in Project, but then doing extra legwork to cascasde jobs, tasks, documents to individuals and teams.